# Looking for a plugin to create floor plan

Tags: php, javascript, flash, plugins, architecture

I am looking to create a website in which I want to give users an option to create the floor plan of their house. I am looking to replicate something like http://floorplanner.com/demo#assets .

I tried to do code it with jqueryui, but found it very hard as I am not a programmer by profession.

Is anyone aware of an open source plugin that I can use in my website to create a similar tool. I searched the net for same (javascript and flash plugins) but did not get what I was looking for. I am not looking for an ideal solution, rather anything that will make it easier for me to make a final product.

Thanks,
SY

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Concerning Javascript/HTML5 approach, probably the best way to solve this problem nowadays would be to make use of some HTML5 canvas library like:
- http://www.kineticjs.com/
- http://fabricjs.com/

or SVG library like Raphael.js:
- http://raphaeljs.com/

However, this is a complex problem and you'll hardly make a good and scalable solution without deeper understanding of Javascript programming.

Take a look at a similar thread, might help you.
[SVG/Canvas vs Flash for FloorPlanner app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118546/svg-canvas-vs-flash-for-floorplanner-app)

Comment: Thanks Josip.
Your answer lead me to the right track. Searched the net and found out this http://keith-wood.name/svg.html#graphcode and http://misterhouse.wikispaces.com/Floor+Plan

These should be a good start.

Meanwhile I will appreciate if anyone can help me with the SVG plugin that may be a good start from my project.

Comment: okay... took a relook at your answer... However I have a query regarding Kinectjs / fabricjs and Raphael - which one would have better online discussion groups.

I am not a programmer, and I generally code using lot of googling.
Thanks again

Comment: I faced a similar challenge and http://fabricjs.com/ is the best solution for my problem. @JosipFilipović thx a lot :)